How do the class libraries know where to find their dependency (other class libraries)?
I hope my title is not too confusing. So I have an assisting assembly and have built it into one dll file (let's call it reference.dll), which I want to use in another project (Let's call it main project).
But to run the main project, for some reason it has to be built into a plugin dll file and called by an application, instead of being built into a direct executable. So when I build the main project, the output actually consisted of separated reference.dll and MainProject.dll (and other class libraries that I use in the MainProject.dll)
So when I run the MainProject.dll in my application, how does it know where to find all these dependencies? My confusion is that when I run the MainProject as an executable (directly from VS2022), I have explicitly add the path of the reference.dll so that it knows where to find it. But I have never do so when I use the MainProject.dll as a plugin from another application. Is it a configuration in my application or in the .NET enviroment that they are reachable as long as all dll files are in the same directory as my MainProject.dll?
And what is the better practice to manage all these libraries. I assume as the project grows larger, there will be problems about dll names collision and confusion when loading them?
Thank you.

Not sure what you are asking. You can create as many project as you want, and as long as you don't have circular dependency, it is all good. Once project is referenced, it is not your concern how .NET builds it - it just does it correctly and I wouldn't go there, without critical need to do so.

Dependency loading in .NET


But I never do so when I use the MainProject.dll as a plugin from another application. Is it a configuration in my application or in the .NET enviroment that they are reachable as long as all dll files are in the same directory as my MainProject.dll?

According to this article, you could find for using the plugin inside the asp.net core, you should add below settings inside the csproj.

The true prepares the
project so that it can be used as a plugin. Among other things, this
will copy all of its dependencies to the output of the project.

<EnableDynamicLoading>true</EnableDynamicLoading>

After enabling this attribute, it will copy all the dll locally and inside your project.When the project is running,  the runtime automatically loads dependencies from that directory.
Besides, for some strong name assembly, it runtime will also load from  global assembly cache (GAC). More details, you could refer to this article.  At last , you could also check this article to understand how Dependency works in asp.net core(as shingo) shown.
